# finding the limit superior and inferior of the sequence $\frac 1 n \cos{\frac{n\pi}{2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, limsup-and-liminf

I'm doing a problem in which I should find the limit superior and inferior of  the sequence $\left\{ \frac 1 n \cos{\frac{n\pi}{2}} \right\}^\infty_{n=1}$

If $n$ is even, then $\cos{\frac{n\pi}{2}}=(-1)^n$ so we have the two subsequences $s_1 = \left\{ -\frac 1 n \right\}$ and $s_2 =\left\{ \frac 1 n \right\}$.

Otherwise is n is odd, $\cos{\frac{n\pi}{2}}=0$, giving the subsequence  $s_3=\left\{ 0 \right\}$.

Since these are the possible subsequences, and $s_1<s_3<s_2$, does this mean that $s_1$ and $s_2$ are the limits inferior and superior, respectively?

Comment: Hint: the sequence converges.

Comment: Given sequence is convergent and converges to $0$. So limit superior and inferior both are zero.

Comment: Oh - is that because $\left\{\pm \frac 1 n\right\}\to 0$? I guess I just stopped too early?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Cuchy’s theorem by starting as cos nπ/2 lies between -1 and 0.(been getting some technical problems with my pc, so can't type it mathematically) since when n is odd, cos nπ/2=-1 and when is even, cos nπ/2=0.
Hence when we consider -1/n < (1/n)cos nπ/2 < 0. As n→∞, (-1/n)→0. Hence both superior limit and inferior limit = 0.